# Using count(*) result field in same query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Hello I am using following query to calculate trends of average number of vulnerabilities per asset. I need to use result of count(*) operation for further calculations, as you can see in my query. Unfortunately, I have error that column scanned_asset does not exist. How can I fix that?

```
SELECT to_char(fad.day, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS day, count(*) AS scanned_assets,
scanned_assets/(SELECT DISTINCT vulnerabilities FROM fact_all_date fadt WHERE 
fadt.day=fad.day) AS avg,
FROM fact_asset_date fad
INNER JOIN dim_asset da USING(asset_id)
WHERE (da.credential_status='All credentials successful' OR 
da.credential_status='Credentials partially successful')
GROUP BY fad.day
ORDER BY fad.day ASC
```

Comment: Use the above as a subquery and perform a select on that?

Comment: @eurotrash Love the screen name :-)

Comment: @Vaurine, This is because you cannot use Column ALIAS in your select list in the same Query .. For this, simple solution would be, in your current SELECT query, for your 'avg' column value, instead of using 'scanned_assets', use formula as : count(*) / (SELECT CLAUSE) ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work?

```
SELECT 
    x.day, 
    x.scanned_assets, 
    x.scanned_assets / (SELECT DISTINCT vulnerabilities FROM fact_all_date fadt WHERE fadt.day = x.day) AS avg
FROM
(SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(fad.day, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS day, 
    COUNT(*) AS scanned_assets
FROM 
    fact_asset_date fad
    INNER JOIN dim_asset da USING (asset_id)
WHERE 
    da.credential_status = 'All credentials successful' 
    OR da.credential_status = 'Credentials partially successful'
GROUP BY 
    fad.day) x
ORDER BY 
    x.day;
```

Edit: Removed square brackets, as POSTGRESQL doesn't like them.

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 2:     x.[day],

Comment: Yes, you will need to remove the `[`s and `]`s that I added around column names that are badly named.

Comment: Unfortunately, avg column equals zero. It should not.

Comment: This is possibly an integer division error, try casting one of the arguments to a decimal, e.g. (not sure of the syntax) `CAST(x.scanned_assets AS DECIMAL)`?  A trick that works in some systems is to multiply one of the arguments by a decimal, as this will then do the cast for you, e.g. `x.scanned_assets * 1.0`.

Comment: @Vaurine Yes.. for one of case in my query, the divisor was 0, hence i added a Decode statement to replace 0 by 1

Answer (score 0):

@Vaurine, This is because in SQL Query, you cannot use Column ALIAS of one column for computation of another Column in Select list of the same Query ..
For this, simple solution would be, in your current SELECT query, for your 'avg' column value, instead of using 'scanned_assets' like below:

```
scanned_assets/(SELECT DISTINCT vulnerabilities FROM fact_all_date fadt WHERE 
fadt.day=fad.day) AS avg
```

Use formula as :

```
count(*) / (SELECT DISTINCT vulnerabilities FROM fact_all_date fadt WHERE 
fadt.day=fad.day) AS avg
```

I used similar query on Emp tables and got the results perfectly fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)/(SELECT DECODE(COUNT(DISTINCT ename),0, 1, COUNT(DISTINCT ename)) FROM emp WHERE emp.deptno = dept.deptno)
FROM dept
GROUP BY deptno;
```

May be in your query, value of count(*) itself is coming as 0, and hence the value of avg is 0.

[image: Query Results on EMP tables]

Comment: I've figured it out before, but in that case avg field shows 0. It is a bad calculation, because I have 2 scanned_assets and found 800 vulnerabilities.

Comment: Yes .. you need to add COUNT on vulnerabilities as well from fact_all_date

Comment: I do not understand your reply. Vulnerabilities is a field which shows total number of vulnerabilities.It is an integer. So if i make count(*)/my query I am dividing int by int.

Comment: so  u mean to say that vulnerabilities sub query will always return one numeric value ?

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: Then y using DISTINCT in the first place ? .. i thought it's because there may be several vulnerabilities being fetched by this sub query ..

Comment: No, becouse accidentally I made more than one snapshot in one of the days. So I have 3 records from fact_all_date when date was 24-07-2018 and vulnerabilities count was 800. Without distinct I would had more than one row returned by subquery). That is not the problem

Comment: I added decode statement to remove the possibility of getting Divide by 0 error